# c# How to reference a dynamically created Combo box?

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I have some code that creates a few combo boxes on the click of a button. Something like this.

```
for (int i =0; i< noCol;i++){
tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount + 1;
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "العمود " + (i+1) }, 0, (i));
var com = new ComboBox();
com.Name = "reportColumn" + (i + 1).ToString();
g = tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[com.Name] as ComboBox;
c.Add(g);
g.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ReportWizardStep1ComboboxSelectedIndexchanged);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(com,1,i);}

private void ReportWizardStep1ComboboxSelectedIndexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e){ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
MainForm.exportReport.getDataGridView1().ColumnCount++;
MainForm.exportReport.getDataGridView1().Columns
            [MainForm.exportReport.getDataGridView1().ColumnCount - 1].HeaderText = g.Text;
comboValues.Add(g.Text);}
```

but, when I run the code, an exception is thrown for this line:

```
g.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ReportWizardStep1ComboboxSelectedIndexchanged);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(com,1,i);
```

the exception is :

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred. how can I solve this problem

Comment: I'm trying to follow your logic.  You create a ComboBox "com".  Then reference a ComboBox of the same name to "g".  Then move "g" to "c's" Control collection.  Then add "com" to the TableLayoutPanel.  So are you trying to replace a ComboBox with a ComboBox?  What are you trying to do that makes you jump through these hoops?

Comment: What is this: `c.Add(g);`? Why are you trying to set `g` to an existing child control of `tableLayoutPanel2`? Aren't you just creating this new ComboBox? The vent handler should be subscribed to by `com`, not this `g` (which is, btw, probably `null` and the whole thing doesn't make sense).

Comment: after creating combo boxes dynamically, I'm trying to handle a "selectedIndexChanged" for everyone by using its reference name. I used this "g = tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[com.Name] as ComboBox;" to get the reference name

Comment: Your code example is not easy to read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The *reference name* (the reference to a newly created control) is `com`. Attach the handler to this instance and add the instance to the collection. `c.Add(g);` still a mystery

Comment: `MainForm` looks like a dangerous reference.  It might not reference the form you see on the screen.  Always pass a reference and use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
var com = new ComboBox();
com.Name = "reportColumn" + (i + 1).ToString();
g = tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[com.Name] as ComboBox;
c.Add(g);
g.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ReportWizardStep1ComboboxSelectedIndexchanged);
tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(com,1,i);}
```

you are creating a new combobox, setting a name and searching this newly created control in tableLayoutPanel2.Controls...it is expected to return you null... you should be adding it first before looking for it.

Comment: thank. It now works well. but the dataGridView1 still not showing any new column headertext added. how can I solve this? I tried "MainForm.exportReport.getDataGridView1().Refresh();" but still not working

Comment: use Application.DoEvents

Comment: Application.DoEvents is not working also

Comment: you are using g.text. you should be using g.name.

Comment: I don't need the combo box reference name to be the header text of the datagridview. I need what the user selects from its items, which are strings

Comment: thank you akhileshcoer it works well now

Comment: you should be marking answer as selected answer